# Replace character with page break in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, page-break, find-replace

In Google Docs I need to string replace a pattern ($$$newpage) with a page break. Is this possible with standard page search? Or do I need to do it programmatically?

Comment: You can *find* a page break with regex -- use \x0C. But it doesn't seem to let you use it as the replace text.